# NGINX do not load for the first time

Tags: nginx, routes, reverse-proxy

I use nginx for reverse proxy and web service on two computers. the proxy forwards the requests to webserver.

Here are the configurations of nginx:
reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen              8000 ssl;
    server_name         129.70.xx.xx;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/vir.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/vir.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.11:8000;
        }
}
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         129.70.xx.xx;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/vir.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/vir.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.11:8001;
        }
}
server {
    listen              8080;
    server_name         129.70.xx.xx;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.12:8080;
        }
}
server {
    listen              7000;
    server_name         129.70.xx.xx;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.12:7000;
        }
}
server {
    listen              7001;
    server_name         129.70.xx.xx;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.12:7001;

        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         vir2.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/vir2.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/vir2.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.11:8001;
        }
}


server {
    listen              8000 ssl;
    server_name         vir2.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/vir2.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/vir2.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.11:8000;
        }
}
```

web service:

```
server {
        listen 8001;
        server_name vir.com;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}
server {
        listen 8001;
        server_name vir2.com;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

To do the debugging the issue, I checked the requests sent by the web service for the first time, no request has been sent to the backend by the website.

Any idea?